# Redirect based on file upload

Tags: php, if-statement

Seems like a no brainer if statement right?  But for some reason.... I cannot get a page to load based on if a file was uploaded properly or not.

This is not the complete page, but this is what I am using atm that somewhat works...

```
elseif ($pn == "umov") {
    ?>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <h1>Movie Updated</h1>
    </div>
    <?php

    $umovim = $_FILES["my_field"];
    if ($umovim > '') {
        include 'eupload.php';    
    }
    if ($umovim == $umovim) {
        include 'update_movie.php';
    }
} elseif ($pn == "inmov") {
    ?>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <h1>New Movie Added</h1>
    </div>
```

Here is what happens...

If I do not upload a photo, the program will call update_movie.php. If I do upload a photo, I get both eupload.php and update_movie.php.

I tried using else and elseif instead of if and I get a blank page meaning that the script is not calling or loading the update_movie.php.

I am not sure what value is being passed by  $umovim = $_FILES["my_field"];.  When I echo the result to the page all it says is ARRAY.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `if ($umovim == $umovim) {`  -> `if(foo == foo)`. Why are you checking if the variable is the same as itself?

Comment: What is `$umovim > ''` supposed to mean?

Comment: $umovim > '' Means that if there is a file uploaded then process the file with eupload.php.

As for your other question that is the only way I can get the page udate_movie.php to load if a photo is not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is actually correct coding but it works...

```
elseif ($pn == "emov") {
        ?>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <h1>Edit Movie</h1>
        </div>
        <?php
            include 'edit_movie.php';
            }
            elseif ($pn == "umov") {
        ?>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <h1>Movie Updated</h1>
        </div>
        <?php

            $umovim = basename($_FILES["my_field"]["name"]);
                if ($umovim > ''){
                    include 'eupload.php';    
                    } else {
                    include 'update_movie.php';
                    }
            }
            elseif ($pn == "inmov") {
        ?>
```

Using basename($_FILES["my_field"]["name"]); instead of just $_FILES["my_field"]; seemed to pass a value that was workable for the else statement.  Although I am not sure what that value is. LOL.